# Krausen gone after 24h. Is it normal?

Tags: fermentation, yeast

I brewed a new batch. I am using extract and a yeast that I have never used before: SafAle BE-256. I got a nice healthy Krausen by the morning after brew day, with massive CO2 activity, but by the following morning, 36h after brewing, krausen was completely gone and CO2 activity decreased quite a bit.

Seems a bit fast so I am worried something has gone wrong.  Can this be normal? Fermentis website says it ferments fast, didnt expect that fast....

Comment: Hi.  There are a lot of questions about krausen, try the search to find similar question.  https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/773/krausen-during-primary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, not all kraüsens stay fluffy during the whole fermentation. There are high and low kraüsens, long lasting and short lived kraüsens. You can't use them as a measure for your fermentation.

Second, I know the BE-256, it is indeed a rather powerful yeast. However, you should give it the normal fermentation time. Sometimes a fast initial fermentation is followed by a longer lasting slower fermentation. Measure your gravity after five days, and then again five days later. This will give you a better indication of the fermentation, and when it is possibly finished.

Also check your ambient temperature and try to make it that it doesn't fluctuate too much. To finish fermentation it is helpful to be able to increase the ambient temperature if possible, or at least to not let it drop under 20° C.

Comment: thanks. appreciate the clarification. will give it time. my ambient temp is a stable 20C in the room so that should be covered.